# Single delegate with multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-protocols

I ran into a situation where I want to register 2 different UIViewControllers with one delegate, because my project is showing 2 UIViewControllers at a time. When I trigger the event, I want both the controllers to get notified, but unfortunately only either controller can receive the event not both.

Here is sample code:

```
@objc protocol DownloaderDelegate: class {
    func complete()
}

class Downloader {
    static let sharedInstance = Downloader()
    weak var delegate: DownloaderDelegate?

    private init() {

    }

    func downloadFile() {
         self.delegate!.complete()
    }
}
```

I am then using it like this in both UIViewControllers:

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Downloader.sharedInstance.delegate = self
}
```

Any idea how to make both the view controllers to listen to event from single delegate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, I think the best solution here would be to move from the delegate pattern to the Notification Pattern (more details on Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Notification.html ).

Another solution would be to replace your delegate by an array of DownloaderDelegate. But I truly think that the Notifications solution is the cleanest and simplest.

Here is a good article on `NSNotification` in Swift:  https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/

**Edit:**
You should take care of observers removal. The simplest way to do so is to add this in each class listening for events:

```
deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How about using the `callbacks`? Because this NSNotification also requires special care of removing the observer.

Comment: `callbacks` could be a solution, but I think it's less simple than `NSNotification`. On observers removing, you just have to do: 

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)` in the `deinit` method.

Comment: Considering it appears you're doing a download, notifications may be your best option considering you may at some point have more things that will want to be aware of a download finishing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a single attribute, so only one thing can exist there. You have numerous options to have multiple VCs react to something. You could have an array of delegates, subscribe to and send notifications, have a container VC that manages the two other VCs, or numerous other approaches.

Comment: are you saying that an instance can act as a delegate for only one object at a given time?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How about using the `callbacks`?

Comment: @harshitgupta "delegate" is an attribute of a class just like any other attribute. You can only have one at a time just like you can only have one of any attribute

Comment: @codelearner If you want access at a class level and want multiple observers, you'll still have to store the callbacks in an array.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I was talking about the other way around. I think there is/was some confusion about what a delegate is, technically.

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not possible. Think of it as this way. The downloader class has a property called 'delegate'. The property can only hold reference to single instance at a time. Hence, it will only invoke methods of the instance, the 'delegate' referring to(the last assigned value).

As @Onejjy said, Notifications would be a good way to achieve it.

But if you want to go for delegate pattern only. I would say put two properties in downloader clss(delegate properties) and assign them accordingly. Then duplicate the "invoking delegate method" code wherever need be.